# JavaScript brute force into web form

Tags: javascript, webforms, brute-force

[image: screenshot of the form]

> Just above the answer box an error would appear on wrong attempt which
> says "Incorrect Answer". Additionally we have unlimited number of
> attempts.

Above is the website preview with detailed information.

Code:

```
<form id="level" method="post"> 
    <label for="answer">Answer:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

So simply here we get to know that the form does not have action source.
The only way (which I know) is to hack through javascript.
Like the one used to spam Facebook and Orkut, where we have to put in the javascript in URI, address bar.

I have built a javascript (for the address bar) to link to the other javascript files.

And if someone know some online javascript brute force script or something online that could be linked through javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As much as I hate to tell people how to do this sort of thing, it's an interesting problem.

I should say first, however, that a brute force solution will likely take too long to be practical. If the solution is 8 characters long, and we try 1 million possibilities per second (a very optimistic assumption), it would take about 5 years to try out all of the possibilities.

Nevertheless, here is some Javascript code that you should be able to modify to fit your needs:

```
var chars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j,","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "];
while(document.getElementById("answerResult").innerHtml != "Correct Answer"){
  var len = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var str = "";
  while(str.length < len){
    str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
  }
  document.getElementId("answer").value = str;
  document.getElementById("level").submit();
}
```

This solution does not actually use brute force. It implements a method similar to [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort). While more fun and simple, it may take a bit longer to finish. If you're an incredibly lucky person, it might be solved on the first iteration.

Comment: Well actually after encoding it into the URI form, and actually running the script from the address bar did not solve the problem, all I see is nothing, actually it did not do anything

Comment: buddy, this is pointless. You clearly don't know what you're talking about and trying to bruteforce a form with javascript is the dumbest thing I've heard in a long time.

Comment: This answer reminds me about that [old joke](http://www.google.de/search?q=mathematician+hot+air+balloon+joke) with the man in the hot air balloon, not knowing where he is. -- You took time to think about the problem, your solution is *technically* correct, but of no use whatsoever. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the script it's connecting to. Use this http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/10/30/event-listener-view-for-firebug/ to see what event listeners are associated with the button. You might also need to download a javascript deobfuscator plugin for firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/

Comment: There seems no script actually working on the page, its all php.

Comment: last time I checked php was server side. So if the page isn't refreshing and you're getting feedback from clicking submit on a form with no action attribute, there is javascript somewhere in there.

Comment: Seriously I tried the above method, and there is no listener event on the form (or the button). It's all server side, and there exists no script on the page except Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

```
static String seqToken(long value) {
        String[] digitsAlpabets = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
                "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
                "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                "6", "7", "8", "9" };

        int codePoint = (int) (--value % 36);
        long higher = value / 36;
        String letter = digitsAlpabets[codePoint];
        return higher == 0 ? letter : seqToken(higher).concat(letter);
    }
```

change the character set as you like and use the size accordingly
To get the sequence generator.